# Repair raid after bad suspension (Error Occurred 0)

Tags: raid, partition-recovery, raid-0

My Zenbook after a standby problem in Xubuntu 14.04 is not booting anymore,   neither Xubuntu nor Windows want to boot.

This screen comes up after BIOS:

[image]

Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> I obtain:

[image]

Option 1, 4 and 5 are disabled, I can only Delete RAID or Reset Disks.

Skipping the first screen shows up grub menu, but both Windows and Linux have boot problem.

How can I solve the problem without formatting the laptop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is reported on this page in the official intel support forum:

https://communities.intel.com/thread/31393

To force the windows booting i have used the update system option in the temporary mode. After that i have reinstalled Intel Rapid Storage Technology (RST) and fixed the error.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by the "update system option" in the "temporary mode"? Windows is on my RAID array and I can't boot into it to access RST.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, Intel falsely accused one of my SSDs of failing.

To ensure this, you can boot a Live Linux USB/Disk (Ubuntu, Fedora, etc), using the **GNOME Disks** utility you can perform **Extended S.M.A.R.T. Self Tests** on the individual disks. On a relatively modern SSD this will take less than an hour to complete.

If there are no issues with Windows booting, you should be able to install and startup the Intel Rapid Storage Technology driver/application. Select the **Manage** tab and then click the drive showing an error or warning icon. There should be an option to select "Mark as normal."

The POST BIOS/UEFI warning should go away after this.

Answer (score -1):

In my case error was not physical and simple solution was additional windows installation to extra drive and then fixed them with intel matrix storage manager. Everything is working again. Sad that intel does not make simple tool to fix it using command prompt or something