# How to assess a RAID0 error?

Tags: hard-drive, boot, raid, raid-0

I read the following post and I am having an issue with my laptop (Acer Aspire S7-392). The drive set up was RAID0. I have little experience in RAID setup, but here is the screen I encounter once booted

[image: Screenshot]

After digging around the forum, I came across this
[Repair raid after bad suspension (Error Occurred 0)](https://superuser.com/questions/956113/repair-raid-after-bad-suspension-error-occurred-0/1186760#1186760)

Does anybody knows how to boot Window despite the RST showing an error? Exiting the RST screen display no boot loader. PC has been working fine until yesterday. Thank you for input. The OS is Windows 10.

Comment: You'ld need to repair your raid, prior to accessing whatever's on it. With a RAID0, a single disk failure usually means you've lost your array. You might be able to boot a separate system and use the RST application, as suggested in the links you're pointing out, ... in order to "fix" your RAID.

Comment: Hello Grawity. Thanks you for your input. Correct me if I am wrong. By the "array" - that is the instruction used by the RAID to look for bits and pieces to assemble the whole file to read? And you think that is corrupted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: due to the mSATA form factor of the S7-392, there is no mean in resetting the tag through RST without buying a mSATA to SATA adapter.

Assessing the RAID0 can be done using Ubuntu boot disc.

Backup file can be done by loading the Window 10 ISO and using command prompt to pull out folders that you need before formating.

Answer (score 0):

For Intel Rapid Storage controllers, a failure in RAID-0 auto-resolves if the drive is still actually good.

- Remove the bad-marked one, start the system. It should only one member disk (the good one) and RAID status FAILED (with red).
- Power off. Reconnect the drive with problem.
- Now the RAID status and drives should be normal/green.

If the drive still show red/error and the system does not boot it means the drive is actually damaged (which unfortunately appears to be your case) and there's not much you can do except use a boot disk and then run a scandisk utility on it to detect the actual problems.

Comment: Hello Overmind. Thanks for input. Alas, I performed google around to know that the laptop is a mSATA slot which is housing the 2x128 GB. I will perform a teardown to locate the hard drive, which I believe from online source sits on the right corner. Connecting to my desktop would be difficult because I don't have the adapter for it. 

So I cannot physically separate the two hard drives. I can try disconnect and reconnect.

Comment: I would like to add to this that I was able to boot the Ubuntu using a USB stick and ran a Disk scan. Both SSD (2x128GB) shows that they have passed the Extended SMART tests, meaning that the components are not faulty or anything.

Comment: If there is no damage you could be in luck and only need to rebuild the boot sector.

Comment: Would you know how I can go about rebuilding the boot sector ? I don't have the Windows 10 disc as it never came with it.

Comment: You can make a disk from the official ISO image on Microsoft's site. If the rest of your data is correctly detected, use such a disk to repair the boot area.

Comment: Ok. I will give this place a try and perform the repair as instructed here. 
http://pureinfotech.com/repair-master-boot-record-mbr-windows-10/

Comment: I have followed your advice but I failed to fix the mbr. However, what I was able to do was using the ISO CMD to enter into C:/ and retrieve my files by copying it out to my external hard drive. So you were correct, the array must have been damaged so it could not boot. All the files that I copied out can be opened fine! 

The solution to my problem, would be to grab the file and reset the RAID. In fact, I would try to un-RAID the drive now I know how risky RAID0 can be. Thanks you overmind for contribution. Case closed