# Laptop Shows Corrupted SSD

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, ssd

I have noticed for a while now my laptop, upon start-up, shows that I have 2 corrupted SSD's. This is concerning because my laptop should be super great. I wasn't too alarmed until I started researching a bit and noticed that while in the Disk Manager I cannot seem to see the SSDs. I only see the HDDs.

Is there something I am missing because on start-up it loos like the SSD's are corrupt but then it looks like they've been cloned and are fine? But if that's true then what would make me unable to see the SSD's in the Disk Manager? If they are corrupted, how can I repair them? I don't care about data loss. I simply would like the disks actually usable and viewable.

Here are some photos:

[image]
[image]

Comment: What is the expected here? How many drives are actually installed? Also, it appears that you have your drives in a Raid0 configuration?

Comment: I am expecting 1 1TB HDD and 2 256 SSDs but I cannot seem to see the SSD. Also, I am not sure what Raid0 means to be honest. Does that mean I have it turned off? Also when I go to the configuration it gives me the option to delete the corrupted ones?

Comment: I appears you have some of your SSDs in a RIAD0 array. A single disk failure in a RAID0 configuration means the entire RAID is offline.  You can rebuild the array with the configuration utility.  The two disks being in an error state is the reason the RAID is offline.

Comment: @KangarooRIOT RAID0 does not mean "no RAID", RAID has different configurations, all numbered. And much like arrays in programming, the first index is index 0, and 1 is the second index (start counting at 0 instead of at 1). What's the background on this computer? If you didn't set up the RAID then who did? Is this a personal laptop, or for work? Did someone own/use this laptop before you? The computer could have come "pre-installed" with the RAID configuration from the manufacturer, but you will need to understand RAID if you're investigating this SSD issue since the SSD is in a RAID.

Comment: I bought the laptop from a colleague and then I factory reset it. How do i solve the issue of being able to actually use these SSDs? Thank you all for helping

Comment: @KangarooRIOT I myself am unfamiliar with RAID, I only know a little bit about it but I've never actually used it before. I believe in the BIOS is where your settings for RAID are. If you still have contact with the colleague maybe ask him if he would know how, otherwise maybe seek YouTube videos on the subject? Sorry I can't be of more help here.

Comment: How many disks do you physically have in the computer?

Comment: @harrymc I am honestly unsure. I was told I had 2 SSDs and 1 1TB HDD. Is there a way I can check?

Comment: Only way is to open up the case and count.

Comment: [Some SSDs appear as two](https://superuser.com/q/1336534/432690). Maybe you have two physical SSDs that appear as four in total.

Comment: @KangarooRIOT: Your bounty is ending. Choose an answer or indicate why they are all unacceptable.

Answer (score 1):

#### Preliminary note

[Some SSDs appear as two](https://superuser.com/q/1336534/432690). Maybe you have two physical SSDs that appear as four in total.

---

#### What you see

> in the Disk Manager I cannot seem to see the SSDs. I only see the HDDs.

You actually see everything you are supposed to see. All four SSDs in question are members of the [RAID0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_RAID_levels#RAID_0) volume with ID `0` (this ID appears in parentheses after `Member Disk` or `Error Occurred`).

If effect the OS sees the RAID volume of 931.5 GB (strictly: [GiB](https://superuser.com/a/373601/432690)) *instead of the four SSDs*, and a non-RAID HDD of very similar capacity. Inability to see member devices is normal when RAID is handled outside of the OS. In your case [Intel Rapid Storage Technology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Rapid_Storage_Technology) handles the RAID. As seen in the photo, you can enter its configuration by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> before the OS even starts. From there you can disassemble the RAID volume and make all its members visible to the OS.

Don't do this (at least not yet). Destroying the RAID will not necessarily erase the data, but it will make it inaccessible until you reassemble an equivalent RAID0.

"The data" means the content of one of the two disks you actually see in the Disk Manager. Formally I cannot tell which one it would be, but because it makes so much more sense to put `C:` on fast SSDs than on slow HDD, I'm pretty certain it would be the disk with `C:`.

There's probably something wrong with two SSDs, but not critically wrong (yet?). I can tell because your Windows still works. The way RAID0 operates makes the entire volume fail after one of the members fails. E.g if one of your SSDs was totally inoperable or missing, then your Windows wouldn't work.

---

#### What to do

> If they are corrupted, how can I repair them?

There is [this question](https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-Desktop-Boards/Error-Occurred-on-the-status-of-my-hard-disk/td-p/187408) in the official Intel support forum:

> This morning, I was restarting my computer and suddenly find out one of my raid 0 hard disk status is displayed as error occurred. the ironic is, my PC is still running like there was no problem. is there anything I should do […]?

And the answer that helped:

> If you installed the Intel Rapid Storage Technology (RST) driver in Windows you can use the RST application to check the status, reset errors, verify the raid, etc.

Also check these questions here on Super User:

- [Repair raid after bad suspension (Error Occurred 0)](https://superuser.com/q/956113/432690)
- [How to clear RAID “Error Occurred(0)” member disk message?](https://superuser.com/q/1123974/432690)

In general the answers agree that working with Intel Rapid Storage Technology software is the right way. I'm not familiar with the software so I cannot guide you in details.

It can happen the two SSDs are really faulty. Then you may want to disassemble the RAID and check them independently in an OS. Not "in the OS" because your current Windows will be inaccessible after you destroy the RAID. It may be they will turn out unreliable and you'd like to scrap them. In such case you will be able to create a new RAID0 (or RAID1 if you want) with the two remaining SSDs.

Or it can happen the software, upon closer inspection, will tell you the SSDs seem fine. I expect the error statuses to be cleared then.

Answer (score 0):

Disk Manager sees only two disks.
One of the two looks like the expected HDD, while the size of the other
is weirdly equal to sum of the four SSDs of about 232 GB each.

One theory might be that they are on a software RAID which the BIOS does not
understand, and the computer actually works fine.

This being Windows 10, it is possible that the four disks take part in one
[Storage Space](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/storage-spaces-in-windows-10-b6c8b540-b8d8-fb8a-e7ab-4a75ba11f9f2),
which the BIOS surely will not understand.
Try to run the command `Storage Spaces` from the Start menu to see if it exists.

You could further check for disk errors by :

1. Check the Event Viewer for disk errors
2. Run `wmic diskdrive get status`
3. Try using [HDDScan](https://hddscan.com/) to have a look at the SMART data
   of the disks